# brother MFC-J435W wireless scanning issue

Tags: wireless, scanner, brother

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I have a brother MFC-J435W and I was able to get the printer set up for wireless printing, but it is not allowing me to scan wirelessly. It gives me the message to "check connection". I'll tell you what I've done so far and maybe someone can help me out.

- I've installed the scanner driver and scan tool
- I installed Xsane (to see if it would allow the scanner to communicate with the computer and that didn't help).
- I've tried restarting the computer.

After those things I am now at a loss as to where to go from here. Any help would be great. Thanks. I've also searched for this question in the Brother FAQ as well as on here and I haven't found an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

head over to [This Page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html) and download the drivers for your scanner. There should be two deb files install them both.

After installing them, execute the command

```
sudo brsaneconfig4 -a name=scanner model=MFC-J435W ip=192.168.xxx.xxx
```

Check that your scanner is registered with

```
brsaneconfig4 -q | grep scanner
```

Your wireless scanner should now be installed

Comment: Been having this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and a Brother J870DW. Those two commands were the missing piece. It works now! Thanks.